# What is causing only 1/6 of my chilli plants in deep water culture to wilt?

Tags: hydroponic

I have set up a hydroponic system indoors and planted 6 chilli plants in one bucket. It's a DWC system where I fill the bucket with water and mix the nutrient solution and submerge the plant roots in it. I have also set up an air pump with dual outlets to aerate the solution. On top, I have grow light strips.

The problem is, out of the 6 plants, one started to wilt. I planted them two days ago. Here are some photos of the setup:

[image]

[image]]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: show us the root systems of the healthy plants, and then check carefully for damage to the stem of the sick plant.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Thanks. I just posted a photo showing the root system of the wilted plant with a healthy one.

Comment: You're using stones?  I only use hydroton which is a light weight expanded clay product.  Suggest you remove that plant from the pot and you'll see stem damage most likely.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Yes I agree. The problem is I could not found hydroton in my country.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Just took the plant out. There seems to be some issue at the base of the plant. Is it a disease or cause by the stones?

Comment: That is root rot M. Watt.  One plant in each 'pot'?  Were these plants grown in soil  originally?  Have you ever grown plants in good old regular soil?  I am a dang expert but just do not see the benefits to grow hydroponically.  Plants were meant to be grown in soil.  Just to be able to grow plants in soil successfully is necessary before considering growing hydroponically.  If SHTF, hydroponic culture will be worthless...unless you've got solar powered hydroponics.  These plants are totally stressed.  If you have one that survives, you will be lucky.  Did you start your plants in soil?

Comment: @stormy Yes I did grow the plants in soil originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences in plant sizes shown for only 2 days in your hydroponics setup suggests that the plants were different at the time they were transplanted into the pots.  The sudden tapering of the stem to the roots suggests that there has been damage to the stem of the affected plant.  It doesn't look rotten so it may just be trauma but the roots you show are brown rather than white so I would worry that you've got a [pythium](http://www.plant-magic.co.uk/post/2015/03/27/pythium-the-hydroponic-plague/49/) infection in your setup.  It could be the lighting you use so I'd check them outside in daylight.

Comment: Is it because I originally planted them in soil? Just washed the roots and planted them in this system two days ago.

Comment: A lot of people who have small hydroponic setups will do that but often the plants are bigger with larger root structures.  Transplanting at such a small size risks root damage from the heavy rocks you're using. But the other plants look okay.

Comment: Great thanks! I will keep an eye on the roots.